# Retrieve image orientation in PHP

Tags: php, image, orientation

How can I get the image orientation (landscape or portrait) of an image (JPEG or PNG) in PHP?

I created a php site where users can upload pictures. Before I scale them down to a smaller size, I want to know how the image is orientated in order to scale it properly.

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimageorientation.php

Comment: that's not part of the jpg/png specs. they're just grids of pixels. you could check if the image is wider than it's taller, but that doesn't mean too much. EXIF data does contain orientiation data.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I've always done this:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize('image.jpg');
if ($width > $height) {
    // Landscape
} else {
    // Portrait or Square
}
```

Comment: You may want to correct the exif data first when using this - as the width height may be reversed in some cases

Answer (score 10):

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize("path/to/your/image.jpg");

if( $width > $height)
    $orientation = "landscape";
else
    $orientation = "portrait";
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using this shorthand. Sharing just in case someone needs a one-line solution.

```
$orientation = ( $width != $height ? ( $width > $height ? 'landscape' : 'portrait' ) : 'square' );
```

First it checks if image is not 1:1 (square). If it is not it determines the orientation (landscape / portrait).

I hope someone finds this helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could check if the Image width is longer than the length for Landscape and for Portrait if the Length is longer than width.

You can do that with a simple `IF / ELSE` statement.

You could also use the function: `Imagick::getImageOrientation`

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimageorientation.php

Answer (score 0):

Simple.  Just check the width and height and compare them to get orientation.  Then resize accordingly.  Straight-forward really. If you are trying to maintain aspect ratio, but fit into some square box you could use something like this:

```
public static function fit_box($box = 200, $x = 100, $y = 100)
{
  $scale = min($box / $x, $box / $y, 1);
  return array(round($x * $scale, 0), round($y * $scale, 0));
}
```

Comment: A picture taken in landscape mode is nevertheless 'upright' with a width > height. Many devices (and browsers) seem able to correctly determine which of the four sides is the actual top, so there *must* be an authoritative mechanism for accomplishing this feat rather than merely relying on intuition. Besides, even if you want to guess and rotate landscape pics into portraits on this basis, which WAY (anti-/clockwise) would you do-so such that you don't accidently end up with an upside-down result? 

Answer (score 0):

I use a generalized scaling down algorithm like . ..

```
   function calculateSize($width, $height){

            if($width <= maxSize && $height <= maxSize){
                $ratio = 1;
            } else if ($width > maxSize){
                $ratio = maxSize/$width;
                } else{
                    $ratio = maxSize/$height;
                    }

        $thumbwidth =  ($width * $ratio);
        $thumbheight = ($height * $ratio);
        }
```

Here max size is the one I initialized to something like 120px for both height and width . . . so that the thumbnail does not exceed that size . . ..

This Works for me which is irrespective of landscape or portrait orientation and can be applied generally

Answer (score 0):

You may want to rotate the image relative to correct the exif data first - when using the 'getimagesize()' width/height check - as the width height may be reversed in some cases, depending on the camera or device used.

```
$rotate = false;
$exif = exif_read_data($source_image);

if($exif['Orientation'] == '6'){
  $degrees = 270;
  $rotate = true;
}
if($exif['Orientation'] == '8'){
   $degrees = 90;
   $rotate = true;
}
if($exif['Orientation'] == '3'){
   $degrees = 180;
   $rotate = true;
}
        
// Now rotate
if($rotate){
  $source_image_string = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_image) or die('Error opening file to rotate '.$source_image);
  $source_image_rotated = imagerotate($source_image_string, $degrees, 0) or die('Error rotating file '.$source_image);
  $rotated_image_saved = imagejpeg($source_image_rotated, $source_image) or die('Error saving rotated file '.$source_image);// Save Rotated
        }

        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($source_image);
        if ($width > $height) {
            // Landscape
        } else {
            // Portrait or Square
        }
```